Nextjs module not found only when importing a simple sum function from my own npm library
I've been stuck on this issue for a couple of days. I hope there's a NextJS (14) compiler expert out there who could help me understand what I'm doing wrong.
I have built a simple npm package containing some interfaces and functions that I want to use in multiple NextJS applications using an app router.
I build this library with tsup and a simple tsup.config.ts like
import { defineConfig } from "tsup"

export default defineConfig({
    entry: ['src/index.ts'],  // Entry point of your package
    outDir: 'dist',           // Output directory
    format: ['esm', 'cjs'],   // Output formats: ESM and CommonJS
    dts: true,                // Generate TypeScript declaration files
    sourcemap: true,          // Generate source maps for easier debugging
    clean: true,              // Clean output directory before each build
    target: 'esnext',         // JavaScript language target
    external: ['react', 'next'],  // Mark React and Next.js as external dependencies
    esbuildOptions(options) {
        options.banner = {
          js: '"use client"',
        }
    },
});

I then run
npm link

and in my NextJS app, I do the same
npm link myPackage

In a server action of my NextJS app, everything is fine until I only import the types.
As soon as I start importing a function, I get the "Module not found" exception when the page using the server action is built.
Even if the function is just as simple as
export function simpleSum(a: number, b: number): number {    
    return a+b;
}

The build doesn't fail if I just have
import { TypeA, TypeB, TypeC } from 'myPackage';

When I do
import { TypeA, TypeB, TypeC, simpleSum } from 'myPackage';

and I don't use simpleSum the build is still ok.
It's when I add a call to simpleSum in my server action that the build fails with the message
Module not found: Can't resolve 'myPackage'

Just to prevent some possible answers...
If I check under node_modules the files of myPackage are there.
The types and the functions are in all these files
List of all the files under /node_modules/myPackage
I've marked my functions.ts file with 'use client' thinking that it was related to an issue with my Server Component and I've also added the esBuildOption you can see in my tsup.config.ts file up above (and I indeed see the 'use client' directive in the imported files).
I've also published my package in NPM and installed it with npm i myPackage to remove the possible issues due to using npm link.
I'm using NodeJS 20.11.0 and NextJS 14.2.3.
Since my library has nothing so secret inside, you could find it under @bpmromandie/kyc_common_types and see if you are able to import and use one of the available functions in your own app.
Thanks to the kind expert who could shed some light on this issue.

Version 1.0.8 of the package on NPM contained the issue.
In version 1.0.9 I've started using tsc as stated in the answer below

I've switched to 'tsc' (instead of tsup) and used a configuration found here Best practices for creating a modern npm package with security in mind
I have to admit I have not understood the difference and the reason why the following configuration is working but I share it here in case someone else will have the same issue with tsup or with a similar configuration like the one above.
I now have a tsconfig.base.json file
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "files": ["./src/index.ts"]
}

Then two different extensions, one for CJS ...
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "ES6",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "outDir": "./dist/cjs",
    "declarationDir": "./dist/cjs/types"
  }
}

and one for ESM modules...
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "ES2022",
            "DOM"
        ],
        "target": "ES2022",
        "module": "NodeNext",
        "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
        "outDir": "./dist/esm",
        "declarationDir": "./dist/esm/types"
    }
}

This config is now generating these files
List of generated files
I guess now the NextJS app is able to choose the files it needs from this list when installing the library
